Is the closest diagonal state to a given state always the dephased original state?
This question is about the following optimization problem:

Given some density matrix $\rho\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ find the diagonal state which is closest to it in trace norm. More precisely, find
$$
\underset{s\in\Delta^{n-1}}{\rm argmin}\|\rho-{\rm diag}(s)\|_1
$$
with $\Delta^{n-1}\subset\mathbb C^n$ the standard simplex of probability vectors.

A naive first guess is that this minimum is attained on $s=d(\rho)$ where $d(A):=(A_{ii})_i$ just collects the diagonal entries, i.e., $d$ is (equivalent to) the dephasing channel.
This is motivated by the following two facts:

If the trace norm is replaced by the Frobenius norm, then $s=d(\rho)$ because minimizing $\|\rho-{\rm diag}(s)\|_2$ amounts to minimizing the individual entries. Therefore, having the diagonal vanish (which is the only thing one can "control" here) is optimal.
For $n=2$ our guess is provably true:


Result. Given any density matrix $\rho\in\mathbb C^{2\times 2}$ one has
$$
\underset{s\in\Delta^{n-1}}{\rm argmin}\|\rho-{\rm diag}(s)\|_1=\begin{pmatrix}
\rho_{11}\\
\rho_{22}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Proof. The key is the qubit formula
$
\|A\|_1^2={\rm tr}(A^\dagger A)+2|\det(A)|
$, i.e., this is valid for all $A\in\mathbb C^{2\times 2}$.
Because $\rho-{\rm diag}(s)$ is a traceless Hermitian matrix—the off-diagonals of which are the same as for $\rho$—our minimization problem simplifies as follows:
\begin{align*}
\min_{s\in\Delta^{n-1}}\|\rho-{\rm diag}(s)\|_1&=\min_{b}\Big\| \begin{pmatrix}
b&\rho_{12}\\\rho_{12}^*&-b
\end{pmatrix} \Big\|_1\\
&=\min_{b}\sqrt{
\Big\| \begin{pmatrix}
b&\rho_{12}\\\rho_{12}^*&-b
\end{pmatrix} \Big\|_2^2+2\Big|\det \begin{pmatrix}
b&\rho_{12}\\\rho_{12}^*&-b
\end{pmatrix}  \Big|
}\\
&=\min_{b}\sqrt{
2|\rho_{12}|^2+2b^2+2\big|-b^2-|\rho_{12}|^2\big|
}\\
&=\min_{b}\sqrt{4|\rho_{12}|^2+4b^2}\\
&=\sqrt{4|\rho_{12}|^2}=2|\rho_{12}|
\end{align*}
and the minimum is attained for $b=0$, i.e., $s=d(\rho)$. $\square$
This begs the question: does this result hold up for higher dimensions, as well?

(This is a Q&A style question meant as a contribution to the list of counterexamples in quantum information)

It turns out that this is not true, and I want to thank Rubén Ibarrondo (UPV/EHU) for suggesting this problem & pointing out Section II.B of this paper (arXiv) to me; therein, the authors consider the pure qutrit state $\psi=(\frac23,\frac23,\frac13)^T$ which is a counterexample because

the trace-norm distance to dephased state $D(|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|)={\rm diag}(\frac49,\frac49,\frac19)$ equals $\frac{4}{9} (\sqrt{3}+1)\simeq 1.214$
on the other hand, the argmin is $s=(\frac12,\frac12,0)$, and the trace distance in question is
\begin{align*}
\big\|\,|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|-{\rm diag}(s)\big\|_1&= \Big\| \begin{pmatrix}
-\frac1{18}  &\frac49  &\frac29  \\
\frac49  &-\frac1{18} &\frac29  \\
\frac29  &\frac29  &\frac19
\end{pmatrix} \Big\|_1 \\
&=\frac{1}{6} (\sqrt{17}+3)\simeq 1.187<1.214
\end{align*}


Another example one may consider is
$$
\rho=\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{6} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{12} \\
 \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{12} & \frac{1}{6} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and note that
$$
\|\rho-{\rm diag}(d(\rho))\|_1=\Big\| \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{6} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{12} \\
 \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{12} & 0
\end{pmatrix} \Big\|_1\simeq 0.685515\,.
$$
Now numerical search suggests that the argmin in question is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac7{12}\\\frac13\\\frac1{12}
\end{pmatrix}(\neq d(\rho))
$$
for which the corresponding trace norm difference equals
\begin{align*}
\Big\|
\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{6} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{12} \\
 \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{12} & \frac{1}{6} 
\end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{7}{12} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{12}
\end{pmatrix}\Big\|_1&=\Big\|\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{12} & -\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{6} \\
 -\frac{1}{4} & 0 & -\frac{1}{12} \\
 -\frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{12} & -\frac{1}{12}
\end{pmatrix}\Big\|_1 \\
&=\Big|-\frac{1}{3}\Big|+\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{12}+\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{12}=\frac23.
\end{align*}
While rigorously proving that this is in fact the argmin is difficult—so this could, theoretically, be a numerical artifact—this does show without a doubt that $s=d(\rho)$ cannot be the argmin in question (as, obviously, $\frac23<0.685515$). In fact, this seems to be "generic" behaviour, i.e., generating qutrit states at random seems to lead to counterexamples quite quickly.
